# Hide some maybe-no-member Pylint errors

Tags: python, python-3.4, pylint

The following `Python` fragment code gets analyzed by `Pylint`:

```
if type(result) is array.array:
    read = result.tobytes()
```

... with the following error for the last line:

```
E:401,22: Instance of 'int' has no 'tobytes' member\ 
 (but some types could not be inferred) (maybe-no-member)
```

The `result` variable is received from an external function. How can I change (correct) the code to make Pylint understand? Or how can I tell it that the result of the function can have other types than int? Or how can I tell it to ignore that particular line? (I favor an answer in this order of the questions)

Comment: In addition to <int>, what are the types that you expect to have ? (Str or bin .. )

Comment: `array` and `int` are enough

Comment: what if you check the type before. if isinstance(result, int) == False:  read = result.tobytes()

Comment: @user3378649 No, but I like more "isinstance(result, array.array)", thanks

Comment: @user3378649 I still have the error, it is only that I like `isinstance` style more than the `type` compare. Don't you think that I would have insisted for a proper answer to reward you?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

Comment: I think this particular issue no longer happens, at least I can't reproduce it given the code sample you posted.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For some reason, pylint doesn't get 'result' may be of the array type (and will be for sure under the 'if' branch). There is currently no way to tell pylint about that, though it will hopefully be possible at some point.  So for now, you can only disable the warning for that specific line by adding `# pylint: disable=maybe-no-member` after the offending statement or right above it. For example:

```
if type(result) is array.array:
    read = result.tobytes() # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
```

or

```
if type(result) is array.array:
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    read = result.tobytes()
```

Comment: An additional explanatory note: adding the specified comment above the line disables the warning for the entire block (http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message)

Comment: The link in the comment above is dead. [This](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message) is the updated link.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled all `no-member` warnings by passing this command line option to pylint

```
--disable=E1101
```

Comment: Not only you disabled all E1101 warnings, good or bad, but you have to remember to add this parameter every time you use the command.

Comment: Well, it's in my VS Code config. You're not manually running your linting command every time you want to lint, right? You can add that option to a pylint rc file as well.

Comment: Config is better, but still disabling all.
Yes, I do running my command every time since I am having mostly scripts and Python is either a hobby or an auxiliary testing tool at work (and they do not config :( ...)

Comment: I disabled the warning completely because I think if your linter is causing you to add anything to your code (comments to disable it), it's a shitty linter and I'd rather not have the warning than have false positives.. What are you using to edit your python programs? Unless it's Microsoft Word, you can probably configure the linter to run through the editor, every time you save and show the errors to you. Or you could install VS Code, the most popular code editor.

Comment: Trouble is the "no-member" check actually does catch a lot of fat finger code problems.  So completely disabling it (while easy to do) will make my life a bit harder by letting the real problems through as well. With the latest pylint versions, I find false positives don't pop up that often.  When they do, I just comment-disable them.

Answer (score 1):

While using PyLint you can generate a configuration pylint file using these command in your terminal

> $ pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc

the generated file handles the errors and warnings that you have to check.
for the no member in particular you can go to line 560, you can find that it ignored.
this configurations will be applied to all your code files.
and you can edit this configuration file, to meet your requirements.

Answer (score -8):

Instead of

```
result.tobytes(),
```

use

```
getattr(result, 'tobytes')()
```

Comment: Changing code to be slower to make pylint happy is not in the spirit of the exercise. The goal is to be informed code can be made better. I come across this all the time and wish pylint would provide type hinting or use eeStructured text or other doc comment strategies to gain hints, but short of this feature, disabling is definitely the only solution (assuming the code is indeed clean already).