# Python - Gmail API - Instance of 'Resource' has no 'users' member

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

[edit] I have now tried the Python quickstart guide on my linux distro and it is working as intended, which makes me believe this is a windows only issue. [end_edit]

Following the Python Quickstart guide found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

The problem I am getting is when using Python, after the

```
service = build('gmail','v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

The next line, which is this:

```
results = service.users().labels().list(userID='me').execute()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Instance of 'Resource' has no 'users' member
```

Now I have tried the .NET quickstart guide and that works. For some reason the API isn't working on python.

My pip install of the google-api-python-client says it is up to date.

I am using googleapiclient instead of apiclient because from what I have read, apiclient was only there for legacy reasons and using it in this code would result in the error "cannot import build from apiclient".

Here is my [pipfreeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5xzT.png)

Quickstart code:

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

Lists the user's Gmail labels.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Gmail API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Gmail API
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])
if not labels:
    print('No labels found.')
else:
    print('Labels:')
    for label in labels:
        print(label['name'])
```

Comment: If you paused in your debugger, could you inspect the dynamic attributes of the `service` variable? If the discovery step worked as it should, then you should see the various root-level Gmail API resources (such as `users()`). If none of them are there, considering you state there is no issue running the same code from a linux machine, I would suspect a network/firewall or caching issue.

Comment: what does "print(dir(service))" and "print(type(service))" show?

Answer (score 3):

It should be pylint issue.
You can disable pylint warnings for a specific line by adding a comment "# pylint: disable=maybe-no-member" after the offending statement.

see [Hide some maybe-no-member Pylint errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657265/hide-some-maybe-no-member-pylint-errors)

http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message

Comment: I don't think the OP's question had anything to do with Pylint. The question was getting a runtime error, instead of a Pylint error