# how to fix "Module 'cv2' has no ---- member pylint(no-member?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to start a project to learn how to use opencv and the first problem I encountered is this : `"Module 'cv2' has no  ---- member  pylint(no-member)` as posted in the picture.

[image]

I have found some information here in Stack Overflow but I'm afraid, I might not be proficient enough to understand what is going on. Could someone point me in the right direction to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you might have a file named `cv2.py` somewhere on your machine other than the original `cv2` module and now python is importing that file rather than the `cv2` module.
Or perhaps you could've downloaded a wrong cv2 module, other than that i don't see anything that could've gone wrong as you don't have a complex code. Try reinstalling the module and/or removing a file named cv2.py (if you've accidentaly created one).

You can check the module by importing the module in the terminal and check for dir, on python console type `import cv2` and then `dir(cv2)`, now you should see all the classes contained in the `cv2` module.

Answer (score 0):

If the program runs correctly then I guess you are facing linting issue which is answer in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657265/hide-some-maybe-no-member-pylint-errors] question.

Solution is to turn off no-member linting error using below command

```
pylint disable=maybe-no-member
```

OR

```
pylint --disable=E1101
```